# What flavorings do you use for sour pickles?

Tags: food-preservation

I'm making sour pickles (salt water brine, no vinegar) and do not have dill, so I've got garlic and black pepper.

What other suggestions do you have for flavorings?

Comment: Your comment seems like you expect Trey to figure out where you're from, and then tell you in your own terms what he very plainly called sour pickles. If you want clarification you should explain what _you_ are referring to.

Comment: @RyanElkins I specifically said 'sour' and specified that means the brine is salt water, not vinegar.  Dill is a flavoring, not a method of preserving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditional *cornichons* are pickled with tarragon, not dill. I love that flavor!

Comment: Thanks, this is the first answer that actually answers the question.  I'll give tarragon a try.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the main ingredient, some additional flavours can be added using the following:

- Coriander Seed
- Yellow or Black Mustard Seeds
- Dried Chillies
- Allspice
- Ginger
- Black Peppercorns
- Bay Leaves
- Juniper berries
- Cinnamon stick
- Fennel seed
- Cloves
- Celery seed

Combinations of the above can provide some really great flavours.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite canning site, the National Center for Home Food Preservation, also includes whole mustard seed in [its recipe](http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/how/can_06/quick_dill_pickles.html) for dill pickles.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used equal amounts of black peppercorns and *crushed red pepper flakes* along with dill and garlic.